# IIS stops responding after recompile

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

I have my web app I'm developing under local IIS (so not not the visual studio embedded one). It works fine, I can go from page to page...

But if I then change the code and recompile, IIS stops responding properly for ~2 minutes. If I attach the debugger, then there's no executing code, but it just won't serve any pages.

If I stop the App Pool in IIS, then I get a 503 error instantly, but I then am prevented from restarting the App Pool for ~2 minutes with error: Cannot Start Application Pool / There was an error while performing this operation. / Details: / The service cannot accept control messages at this time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070425)

As you can imagine, this is crippling my productivity. Only started happening a couple of days ago, I haven't made any changes to the code which I would have though would cause this problem... and it doesn't matter which page I touch and recompile anyway, it takes just as long to recover. Nothing in the event log.

Any clues as to where to start looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your web.config:

```
 <compilation optimizeCompilations="true" />
```

related article: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/135019/a-small-webconfig-setting-that-can-save-you-development-time

Comment: Seems to have solved the problem! I was expecting this to be helpful in general, and the other option to solve the specific problem I was having... but this has sorted it out. 

Dev web.config now has 
<compilation debug="true" batch="true" optimizeCompilations="true" targetFramework="4.6">

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the installation of the following hotfix fixed the problem for me:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-uk/kb/3090034

Comment: I've installed the hotfix anyway, but the problem was cleared (to my surprise) by the web.config change on the accepted answer.